# Custom Function to get Cell Value by Cell Color in Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have conditional formatting in my google sheet to fill certain cells with different colors according to their values(dates). I made custom functions GetHex() to get cell color and GetColoredCellValue() to return the cell value with the hex code "#ff0000" but the latter function is not returning anything after I put a cell range in Google Sheet
`=GetColoredCellValue("A2:HF2")`

I've never coded seriously before nor used Excel thoroughly so I'm sorry if my code does not make sense. And thank you in advance!

These are the functions i've written.

```
function GetHex(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange(input);
  var result = cell.getBackground();
  return result
}

function GetColoredCellValue(input){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(input);
  var cell;
  for(var i=0; i<range.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<range[0].length; j++){
      cell = range[i][j];
      if(GetHex(cell)== "#ff0000"){
        return cell.getValues();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i run the code in AppScript the Execution Log shows this error

> Execution log
> 2:08:43 PM    Notice  Execution started
> 2:08:43 PM    Error
> Exception: Invalid argument: range
> GetHex    @ Code.gs:3

I wanted to get the cell value of cells with "#ff0000" bg color from each row in a different column. And the template for my spreadsheet would look like this.
I attached a screenshot of what my table in spreadsheet would look like as an example.

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tdd5.png)

Comment: `var range = ss.getRange(input);` "range" is a range is doesn't have a length. I'm also not sure whether it might be a reserved word, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `range` of `var range = ss.getRange(input)` is a Class Range object. So, `range.length` returns `undefined`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- And also, when `GetHex(cell)` is used in a loop, the process cost becomes high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function GetColoredCellValue(input) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var range = ss.getRange(input);
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var dstValues = values.map((r, i) => (r.map((c, j) => backgroundColors[i][j] == "#ff0000" ? c : null)));
  return dstValues;
}
```

- When this script is used as `=GetColoredCellValue("A2:HF2")`, the cell values of the background color of `#ff0000` are returned.
- When you want to ignore the cells except for `#ff0000`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var dstValues = values.map((r, i) => (r.map((c, j) => backgroundColors[i][j] == "#ff0000" ? c : null)));
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var dstValues = values.flatMap((r, i) => (r.flatMap((c, j) => backgroundColors[i][j] == "#ff0000" ? c : [])));
    ```

#### References:

- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this one! I used r.flatMap to ignore cells as u mentioned! I do have another problem since I decided I do not want to use A1notation for input since I plan to use the custom funcition for multiple rows and editing each cell reference would be rather tedious. But that's another post to discuss i guess! Thank you so much again!